# Using Shrine uploader with Google Drive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, google-drive-api, shrine

I'm looking for an image and PDF upload solution for a Rails 4.2 app. Can shrine be used with Google Drive? I see documentation for use with Google Cloud Storage, but nothing about Google Drive. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shrine can be used with any storage, someone just needs to write an integration gem for a given service. The [website](http://shrinerb.com/#external) holds the list of all existing integration gems, and Google Drive isn't on the list yet.

If you want to create the Google Drive integration, I wrote a [guide](http://shrinerb.com/rdoc/files/doc/creating_storages_md.html) on creating new storages.

Comment: awesome. i will check out the guide!